# How to get my place in top from QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I think I have a pretty common task for projects with gamification part.

For example, you have model that stores all users solutions and each solution has scores amount

```
class Solutions(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
    for_top = models.BooleanField()

    def get_place(self):
        return list(Solutions.objects.filter(for_top=True)).index(self) + 1
```

Is there any way to find more optimized solution for the method `get_place`?

Answer (score 0):

```
next(i for i, x in enumerate(Solutions.objects.filter(for_top=True), 1) if x is self)
```

Basically this uses two optimisations. `next(iterable)` instead of `list(iterable).index` is the obvious one: instead of storing everything in memory, `next` iterates through and returns the first item. So it short-circuits and doesn't hog memory.

Additionally, this uses `is` instead of `==`, which is a faster operation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I'm looking for more DB optimized version.